# I can't make a solution folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have Vs 2010 ultimate yet I can't make a solution folder.

http://img208.imageshack.us/f/screenshot001vu.jpg/

How can I get it to show up?

Comment: how is it related to programming? Try right click on Core in solution explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot, it doesn't seem that you have a solution saved yet, just a project.

Did you try saving a solution first?

Comment: I figured it out. If you have only one project it does not show the soultion project that you need to click on to add the solution folder. So I just had to enable it in the options.